# Basic PRINT LIN(2)

Tags: basic

I was looking through the [1975 Oregon Trail Basic Code](https://www.filfre.net/misc/oregon1975.bas) and found this line in it:

```
PRINT LIN(2)
```

I have searched quite a few places but can't find any reference to it.

Can anyone tell me what this means?

**Edit:**
Sorry, I was wondering what the `PRINT LIN(2)` meant. Does anyone know what that means?

Comment: Found a copy of the code at https://www.filfre.net/misc/oregon1975.bas (no thanks to OP).

Answer (score 2):

"Oregon Trail" source of 1975 at [www.filfre.net/misc/oregon1975.bas](https://www.filfre.net/misc/oregon1975.bas) was written in BASIC for a HP-2100 system.

This [HP-2100](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_2100) system was a series of minicomputers produced by Hewlett-Packard.
This system run an interpreted BASIC named "[HP Time-Shared BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Time-Shared_BASIC)".

This is the reference manual of "[TimeShared BASIC/2000 Level F](http://www.bitsavers.org/pdf/hp/2000TSB/2000F-rm-300.pdf)".

About:
PRINT LIN(2)
Generates a carriage return and 2 (two) line feeds.

---

"Oregon Trail" for year 1978 at [www.filfre.net/misc/oregon1978.bas](https://www.filfre.net/misc/oregon1978.bas)  was written using BASIC for "CDC Cyber range of mainframe-class supercomputers of Control Data Corporation (CDC)".

Documentation

http://bitsavers.org/pdf/cdc/cyber/lang/basic/

[**19983900K_BASIC_Version_3_Reference_Manual_Aug84.pdf**](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/cdc/cyber/lang/basic/19983900K_BASIC_Version_3_Reference_Manual_Aug84.pdf)

---

I compare both sources (strip line number without reference by THEN, GOTO or GOSUB) at
 [Oregon Trail Compare](http://www.geocities.ws/alvalongo/c64/oregon_trail/oregon_compare.html)

Comment: I didn't see any reference to the `PRINT LIN()`. Did I miss it or is it in there somewhere?